# Code is doing more swapping compared to human-level method

Tags: c

If a human wants to re-arrange the numbers `1,2,3,4` from the biggest to the smallest, the human will check to see if the second number is bigger than the first number, but will not swap locations until done examining the rest of the numbers.

The new order becomes : `4,2,3,1`

However the code below will swap the locations of "`1`" and "`2`" soon as it determines "`2`" is bigger than "`1`".

The new order becomes : `2,1,3,4`

The program will do more swapping than a human will be doing..
and thus perhaps it is less efficient than human method ?

Is there a way to apply the efficiency of human method to this program ? or perhaps the human method is not more efficient but simply appears that way ?

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
int total;
total = 4;

int i;
int i2;
int holder = 0;

for (i=0; i<total;) {

    for (i2=i+1; i2<total;) {

    if(a[i] < a[i2]) {
    holder = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i2];
    a[i2] = holder;
    }

    i2=i2+1;
    }

i=i+1;
}
```

Comment: You are making assumptions on what algorithms humans typically use. I would usually use [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) when sorting by hand.

Comment: When humans looks at a simple problem like this, they look at the problem as a whole, and compute the final answer. And afterwards look for the optimal swap. Which is to say that the first step for a human is to compute the final sorted array. A computer doesn't see the problem as a whole, and can't make the jump to the final array.

Comment: @user3386109, I think the human mind holds in the memory the number, then looks for a number that is bigger, and if it finds a number that is bigger, it will then look for a number that is even bigger than the previously bigger number, if a number that is bigger number is found, bigger number is swapped with the previous bigger number. So perhaps there is actually more for loops going on in the human mind. Things are kept in a "memory" in other words in a "holder" or a "buffer" rather than doing swapping. The human mind is holding data in a "thought" until there is no more items to check.

Comment: @SümerKolçak *"If a human wants to re-arrange the numbers 1,2,3,4 from the biggest to the smallest"*, then the human notes that 1,2,3,4 are the first four natural numbers, and therefore the answer is simply to count backwards from 4.

Comment: @user3386109, The human can not know that until it checks and verifies everything. However perhaps it verifies things differently than the code in the question. It probably has more "for loops" and holds things in a buffer ( thought ), rather than re-arrange things too many times. Perhaps the code does not use the human-level method because it wants to avoid too many "for loops". But maybe more "`for loops`" would have made the entire code more efficient given that on the human level it does make things more efficient.

Comment: Apparently you're comparing [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) (computer) vs [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) (human).

Comment: @pmg, "wikipedia" is banned in this country I am in of right now, name of the country is "Turkey". However I am doing my best to do research and read about the concepts.

Comment: @SümerKolçak -- Wow! That's a very severe handicap :(

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the opinions below are my own, regardless of any literature that might exist on the topic. They are not supposed to be considered science, regardless of how "science" might be defined.

---

The short answers:

1. We have no idea how the human brain actually works - referring here to mathematical computations, comparisons etc.
2. It is guaranteed that the human brain works radically different from any computer.

---

Maybe I am not accurate in my "metaphor", but I reached this conclusion: the human brain does many (most?) calculations "visually": you just look and you know the correct answer. A computer would need very complex algorithms, and it might still not be able to solve the problem.

Also, the human brain is able to generate a totally different problem, with the same result / answer like the original, but a lot easier to calculate. And that, without us even being aware of that, most of the times.

It was already mentioned in a comment: for the example of your problem, a human would not sort that list of digits. He would just countdown from 4 to 1.

If the problem would provide different numbers, e.g. {5, 21, 48, 16}, the brain cores would "visually" detect the maximums and minimums in the list, and rearrange them in the correct order, without real comparisons (at least, we are not aware of them).

---

The human brain is definitely multi-core. But the cores are not independent like in a computer, which only exchange some data. They are permanently reconfigurable, and I suspect that these "cores" of the brain actually overlap, not only regarding data, but also regarding execution.

---

To understand the kind of computing done in "biological computers":

References: [Rod_cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_cell), [Cone_cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell), [Optic_nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_nerve)

Math:

- **100 million** rod cells;
- **7 million** cone cells;
- Each human optic nerve contains **between 770,000 and 1.7 million** nerve fibers

Now you see, a max of 1.7 million optic nerves connect 107 million sensors to the brain. That is actually the "definition" of **image / video compression**. The eye (retina?) is a standalone computer in itself. If it is able to do video compression, then it MUST be able (my opinion) to sort a short list without the need to relay the data to the brain. That could be an explanation WHY we know an answer to a problem just looking at it - we receive the answer together with the problem - all work was done elsewhere.

---

It seems "obvious" that the biological computers perform mathematical comparisons at some level, it is just that we have no idea where and how they are made. Maybe in a low level "driver"? Maybe they are off-loaded to some other processing unit? A "hardware accelerator"? Maybe, hopefully, the future will tell us.

Comment: If the code in the question is processed by a robot, and this robot has arms to re-arrange the numbers, and if this robot is presented to the whole world as a "role model" this robot could ruin the world if humans copy the method of this robot because it would be constantly re-arranging the numbers and spending lots of energy.  As far as the "human would simply count 4 to 1" argument.. that can only happen if the human verifies things, that verification method is the process in focus.

Comment: Congratulations for your answer, I am with you, especially in the phrase "we don't know how the human brain works".

Comment: @SümerKolçak: It is obvious that we should strive to make computer algorithms better and better, and increase their efficiency as much as possible. However, your questions compares a "simple" robot with the human brain. And I just "proved" that each eye has its own very powerful computer, able to do video compression.